# bootstrap3: native Hide/Extend menu functionality using More Options & Less Options buttons

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap 3, I created a menu that has More Options, when clicked it shows more buttons ending with Less Options button, and hides the More Options, the opposite for Less Options.

I managed to do it using jQuery script and HTML code, my question is: is there a more native bootstrap 3 to get these results? my problem using data-toggle is that I couldn't find a way implementing this using data-toggle="collapse" that bootstrap 3 offers.

jQuery:

```
$("#moreOptionsButton").click(function(){
$("#moreOptionsButton").hide(); 
   $("#extraMenu").show();
});

$("#lessOptionsButton").click(function(){
$("#moreOptionsButton").show();
    $("#extraMenu").hide();
});
```

and HTML code:

```
    <div class="menuButton" id="moreOptionsButton">
      <div class="row">
          <button class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 btn btn-lg">
            <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;More Options</span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="extraMenu" class="collapse">
      <div class="menuButton">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 btn btn-lg">
            <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Location</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="menuButton">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 btn btn-lg">
            <span class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="menuButton" id="lessOptionsButton">
        <div class="row">
          <button class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 btn btn-lg">
            <span class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Less Options</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with adding `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#extraMenu"` to your buttons:

```
<div class="menuButton" id="moreOptionsButton">
  <div class="row">
      <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#extraMenu" class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 btn btn-lg">
        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;More Options</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="extraMenu" class="collapse">
  <div class="menuButton">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 btn btn-lg">
        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Location</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menuButton">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 btn btn-lg">
        <span class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menuButton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#extraMenu" id="lessOptionsButton">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 btn btn-lg">
        <span class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Less Options</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

From http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse:

> Just add data-toggle="collapse" and a data-target to element to
>   automatically assign control of a collapsible element. The data-target
>   attribute accepts a CSS selector to apply the collapse to. Be sure to
>   add the class collapse to the collapsible element. If you'd like it to
>   default open, add the additional class in.

In your case `#extraMenu` is your CSS selector